# Method execute server doesn't response for 7 sec

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have function named as `validate_account()` that return boolean. It goes to db, and do some manipulation with duration of **7** seconds. So, when I make another requests to server, it doesn't response during these 7 seconds for any request. How can I fix it? Maybe by starting new process?

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def check_account(request):
    username = request.session['current_account']

    account = get_object_or_404(Account, username=username)
    # takes 7 seconds
    login_status = validate_account(account.username, account.password)

    response = {
        'loginStatus': login_status
    }

    response = json.dumps(response)

    return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

I am running server as `python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload`

Comment: did you try optimizing the validate_account() function?

Comment: @SurbhitWagle Unfortunately, I can't optimize it. Can I do it in another way?

Comment: Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  . Yours is classic XY problem

Comment: @Sniper realy? XY problem? Look, ok, if I even optimize it (I can't do it), so what? Server wil don't response for 3 seconds instead of 7? What if I have 50 users and 10 of them will attempt to call this request? What about other 40 users, that can't refresh pages?

Comment: Which server are you using, and which database?

Comment: Django's `User.check_password` works in a few milliseconds. Why do you need several seconds to process your own validate_account?

Comment: @HåkenLid This model do not extend AbstarctBaseUser, it is another

Comment: @knbk Now i am running it on my local machine. Database MySQL. But, this 7 seconds сaused by validate_account operations, it connects to site, trying to login as human user, if login successful returns True. Unfortunatly there are no way to optimise it.

Comment: You need to use version/implementation of python that supports multi-threading.. hopefully there is one.

Comment: So you're using `manage.py runserver`? What's your Django version?

Comment: @knbk Right to the point! I run my server as `python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload `. Add it as answer, I will mark it as right

Comment: I'm not sure how that comment answered your question, but I added an answer nonetheless :)

Comment: @knbk You answer why it so slow :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--nothreading` option disables multithreading, so you will only have one thread responding to requests. Since each thread handles requests synchronously, this causes the exact behaviour you describe.

Simply remove the `--nothreading` option, and multithreading will allow the server to respond to multiple requests at the same time. In production, you should also use multiple threads and/or processes to run your WSGI server